# How to Set Binding Path Value Programmatically

Tags: wpf, binding

I have `Style` configuration in my XAML file:

```
<Style x:Key="CostEstimatesDataGridRowStyle" TargetType="controls:DataGridRow" BasedOn="{StaticResource ReportDataGridRowStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True" >
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static controls:Converters.AndValueConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="IsEmpty"/>
                        <Binding Path="IsPrinting">
                            <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                <RelativeSource
                                      Mode="FindAncestor"
                                      AncestorType="{x:Type controls:SinglePageReport}"
                                    />
                            </Binding.RelativeSource>
                        </Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

This style is applied in `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EstimateGridTemplate">
        <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=Category.Category}">
            <GroupBox.Content>
                <Grid>                      
                    <controls:DataGrid

                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Estimates}"

                        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource CostEstimatesDataGridRowStyle}">                            
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox.Content>
        </GroupBox>
    </DataTemplate>
```

My question is how can I set `IsPrinting` value programmatically?